# Variant of identity for a sum of binomial coefficient (Hockey-stick)

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, approximation, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

There is this well known [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) for binomial coefficients:
$$\sum_{t=0}^k\binom{n+t}{t}=\binom{n+k+1}{k}$$
But what's interesting is that a very similar (approximate) identity holds for a thing similar to binomial coefficients. Let's define:
$$\binom{n}{k}_2:=\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k},$$
which is something like the "normed" binomial coefficient. I have found this to hold for $k<n$:
$$\sum_{t=0}^k\binom{n+t}{t}_2\approx\binom{n+k+1}{k+1}_2\frac{2k}{n-k}.$$
Yes, it is not too formal, I did it on a computer. But, I can formalize one conjecture:
$$\frac{\sum_{t=0}^k\binom{n+t}{t}_2}{\binom{n+k+1}{k+1}_2}\to\frac{2c}{1-c}\hspace{12pt}\text{as}\hspace{12pt}n\to\infty,$$
where $0<c<1$ is a fixed constant and $k=\lfloor cn\rfloor$.

I am not very qualified for this but I am eager to understand this phenomenon. I tried to derive this using generating functions for $\binom{n+k}{k}$ and $\binom{n+k}{k}_2$, but I failed to make it to the end. Any insight is very welcome.

### Progress:

With the insight of Rezha Adrian's answer, we have arrived at:
$$\frac{\sum_{t=0}^k\binom{n+t}{t}_2}{\binom{n+k+1}{k+1}_2}=2\frac{\sum_{t=0}^k\binom{n+k+1}{t}}{\binom{n+k+1}{k+1}}.$$
With the substitutions: $n\leftarrow n+k+1$ and $k\leftarrow k+1$ we get the equivalent of:
$$\frac{\sum_{t=0}^{k-1}\binom{n}{t}}{\binom{n}{k}}\to\frac{c}{1-2c},$$
where $k<\frac{n}{2}$ and $c=\frac{k}{n}$ is constant.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074135

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**

Incomplete solution, just some ideas

**Combinatorial Argument**

Toss a fair coin repeatedly until you get $n+1$ tails. The probability of tossing the coin a total of $n+k+1$ times is given below:

$$
P = \frac{1}{2^{n+k+1}}\binom{n+k}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{n+k}{k}_{2}
$$

Following the probability argument, we have :

$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+t}{t}_{2} = 1
$$

**Connection with your observation**

Suppose we toss the coins until either we have $n+1$ tails or we have tossed $n+k+1$ times, denote the probability of the former as $c$ and the later as $1-c$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{t=0}^{k}\binom{n+t}{t}_{2}&\propto c \\\\
\sum_{t=k+1}^{n}\binom{n+k+1}{t}_{2}&\propto 1-c
\end{aligned}
$$

Then we have the following relation:

$$
\frac{\sum_{t=0}^{k}\binom{n+t}{t}_{2}}{\sum_{t=k+1}^{n}\binom{n+k+1}{t}_{2}}
=
\frac{2c}{1-c}
$$

For the rest, I think it has something to do with limit as $n$ becomes larger and larger.

Comment: Great perspective! Just what does $\propto$ mean exactly? Hmm... I think it could be an equal sign??

Comment: So my sum is equal to 2 times the probability that when sampling an infinite stream of bits, I have sampled at most $k$ ones in the first $n+k+1$ bits. And the thing below the fraction line is 2 times the probability that in a stream of bits I have sampled exactly $k+1$ ones in the first $n+k+1$ bits and that the next bit is $0$. Or simply that I have sampled exactly $k+1$ ones in the first $n+k+1$ bits. Just placing this observation here...

Comment: @donaastor it means proportional to :)